# android opencv - is it possible to catch a different click on 3D object per rotation?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, artoolkit

I got a task to do in the Augmented Reality subject.
I need to develop an android app with augmented reality, where i have an image target that i can scan with my camera, and i need to display a 3D object on it.
Now the problem is this, let's say i have a 3D object of a cube. I need to have the ability to control the click of every side of my 3D cube.
if i click on one side of the cube, i'll be able to do one thing, and if i click on another side of the cube, i'll be able to do another thing.

I'm using  the ARToolkit framework which based on opencv. I'm using the AR simple project of the ARToolkit SDK, the source code i took from here:

https://github.com/kosiara/artoolkit-android-studio-example

The opencv libraries were made with c++.

hopefully you guys can help me, I've been searching for hours for a solution. I've searched for other frameworks, and tried doing it myself, but i had no success in this.

Answer (score 1):

as for controlling clicks in general I recommend reading this post here: [Virtual button in ARToolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814345/virtual-button-in-artoolkit/37838536#37838536)

Also I think that you maybe better of if you implement your App using Unity3D and the ARToolKit Unity plug-in.

Once you are able to click on your cube using the suggested technique from the other post you can check at each click how the rotation of your cube is. Based on this rotation you should be able to figure out which side of the cube was clicked.

I hope this gives you a starting point for your App.

Best